# Analytic Function vs Exponential Order function

Tags: real-analysis, laplace-transform

We say that a function $f$ is of exponential order $\alpha$ if there exist constants: $M$, $\alpha$, $T$ such that for $x>T$
$$f(x)<M\cdot e^{\alpha x}$$
Polynomials are of exponential order. Then, is it true that analytic functions in a neighborhood of the origin are of exponential order?

I want to know this to see if it is legal to calculate the Laplace transform of analytic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no, take for example $e^{x^2}$.

Comment: How do we know this function is analytic?

Comment: It is the composition of analytic functions. (Or you can write down an explicit convergent Maclaurin series for it. Or you can use a complex analysis argument.)